# showing that $\sum_1^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}$ is increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series

Define $u_n$ as :

$$u_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}$$

From first values, $(u_n)$ seems to be increasing.

From squeezing, its limit is $1$.

$$ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} \le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}} \le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$

(summing from $k=1$ to $k=n$)

How can one show that it's indeed increasing (if it is) because no terms cancel out when setting $u_{n+1}-u_n$.

thanks.